# When I insert data to database in Celery, some data is missed

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, rabbitmq, celery

I inserted data with RabbitMQ+Celery+flask+sqlalchemy ORM.
Celery workers are total 16 count on two servers.
The number of data is about one million.

If data is queued one by one to MQ and inserted one by one from Celery,
everything is OK.
All data is inserted well.

But When I try to bulk insert using forloop in celery by some size(about 5000, 1000 and so on), some data is missed. 
I write so many logs, but I can't find any error or special thing.
(If number of data is 100,000 instead 1 million, It is OK too)

The simple logic is..

tasks.py

```
@celery.task(bind=True, acks_late=False, ignore_result=True, max_retries=None)
def insert_data(self):
    logger.info("START")
    InsertData(somedata..)
    logger.info("END")

@celery.task(bind=True, acks_late=False, ignore_result=True, max_retries=None)
def insert_data_bulk(self):
    logger.info("START")
    for i in range(5000):
        InsertData(somedata..)
    logger.info("END")

def InsertData(data):
    logger.info("Insert START")
    # my_db_engine's option : {'echo': True, 'pool_recycle': 3600, 'pool_size': 10, 'pool_reset_on_return': 'commit', 'isolation_level': 'AUTOCOMMIT'}

    ss = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False,
                                       bind=my_db_engine))
    t = mymodel(**data)
    ss.add(t)
    ss.commit()
    logger.info("Insert END")
```

test.py

```
for i in range(1000000):
    insert_data_one.apply_async() # make one million messages for MQ

for i in range(200):
    insert_data_bulk.apply_async() # make 200 message for MQ
```

**insert_data_one is do well.**

> log is..
>
> > 1. START
> > 2. Insert START
> > 3. Insert END
> > 4. END

**but insert_data_bulk make some missed data randomly!!**

> log is..
>
> > 1. START
> > 2. Insert START
> > 3. END (3. Insert END <- log is missed sometimes.)
> >        or..
> > 4. START
> > 5. END (2, 3 is missed. I never find them)

The total row count in database is different at any time.

I don't set timeout of Celery.
Database's timeout is matched with my sqlalchemy option.

Do you have any Ideas about it?
Please give any hints to check ;-(

Comment: Sounds like `sqlalchemy` problem. Are you sure is support all those concurrent connections/writes? try to make it with [chains](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) rather than for loop (which is kind of `group` in celery term.

Comment: @ItalyB thanks for your reply. But I need to call one api and write the response to database with splitted rows. the api is not allowed to call multiple times and it returns many data at once. So I think I can't make it as you let me know..

Comment: It seems like you aren't flushing your session. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: I'll try to flush the session. Thanks for hint :)